# DHX Spreadsheet - Unable to select from Column A to D

Tags: reactjs, spreadsheet

Tried creating DHX spreadsheet into my react application, followed the website guide https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxSpreadsheet-for-React/#how-it-works.

However when the spreadsheet is rendered out in my application, i notice that no matter what i do i can't select the Column A to D.

Have anyone faced this issue as i did?

https://gitlab.com/patrickklze/trying_dhx_spreadsheet.git

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5GZc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found and fix the issue.

Somehow it inherits the main css file and text align everything to middle which causes the columns to have bugs.

Add a inline styling on the component tag in your app.js for example:

```
<span style={{textAlign:"left"}}>
   <SpreadsheetComponent />
</span>
```

Would solve the issue.